# crear un header a una petición post angular

Tags: nodejs, tokens, angular9

/Buenos dias, estoy en un proyecto en angular y necesito pedir los datos del usaurio a una api, estoy usando jason web token para sesiones, cada vez que haga una peticion al servidor necesito enviarle mediante el header la propiedad `token` con el valor del token, tengo el siguiente codigo pero no es correcto, necesito ayuda

```
getToken(){
  return localStorage.getItem('token')
}

dataUser(){
  let headers = new Headers()
  headers.set('token', this.getToken())
  return this.http.head(this.URL + 'user-data', {headers: {"token": this.headers}})
}
```

//tengo una validacion en el backend que es el siguiente

```
console.log('Header: ' + req.header())
console.log('body: ' + req.body)

try {
    const token = req.header('token');
    if (!token) return res.status(401).json('Access Denied');
    const payload = jwt.verify(token, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET || 'token') as IPayload;
    req.userId = payload._id;
    next();
} catch (e) {
    res.status(400).send('Invalid Token');
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué parte *no es correcto*?. Podrías añadir el error o el comportamiento que obtienes actualmente y cuál sería el comportamiento deseado? Saludos

Comment: en el archivo del backend estoy mostrando por consola el header, la idea es que llegue el header al backend para corroborar el token pero no llega, la consola me devuelve `undefined`

Comment: Pues yo usaría un [interceptor HTTP](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) para establecer el valor del token en la cabecera en cada solicitud. Tal como lo tienes no lo veo muy claro. Por otro lado, es común usar `Bearer <token>` como valor de una cabecera cuyo nombre sea `Authorization`. Pero eso ya es otro tema. Saludos